# Problem with Selenium, unexpected behavior while running headless

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge

I have trying trouble with trying to run Selenium in headless mode. I have using a find element for an out of stock button, when I run normal with the headless option commented out, I get expected behavior. When I run in headless, I get the wrong result. This is on the new Selenium beta for Java. (4.0) I'm using the beta because the old version does not have options to run Edge headless.

I have tried setting a duration, just takes longer to get the same wrong answer. And I have tried enabling the window size to full screen. No dice.

```
public class BestBuy extends Thread
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "Driver file path");
        final EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
        
        //edgeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        
        WebDriver BestBuyDriver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);

        BestBuyDriver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/site/dyson-airwrap-complete-styler-for-multiple-hair-types-and-styles-fuchsia-nickel/6284230.p?skuId=6284230");

        try
        {
            List<WebElement> buttonText = BestBuyDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[text()='Sold Out']"));
            List<WebElement> text = BestBuyDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Sold Out')]"));
            //BestBuyDriver.findElement(By.className("btn-disabled"));
            if(buttonText.size() > 0 || text.size() > 0)
                System.out.println("Item out of stock");
            else
                System.out.println("Item in Stock");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: No. I got rid of the proxy arguments but now it is running extremely slow. Edit: but does give the right answers.

Comment: it is running slow cause of `findElements` ?

Comment: I made some tests with your code, and I found that the results are the same in headless mode and normal mode. It indeed runs slower in headless mode **with the url you provide**. But if I test with other urls, the time cost is the same in headless mode and normal mode. For example, you can try to test with this url: `https://www.amazon.com/DualSense-Wireless-Controller-PlayStation-5/dp/B08FC6C75Y/ref=lp_16225016011_1_6`. So I think the slow performance is related with the certain website.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you that's good to know.